# check Timestamp for '0000-00-00' without casting

Tags: java, mysql, sql, casting

I know `java.sql.Timestamp` does not accept `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` as a value (with good reason). But the database I am handling was created with PHP and other tools, that don't seem to care.

**what I want**

what I want is to copy the data from one database to another and while doing that, change some values on the fly (like the `Timestamp 0000-00-00`)

**how**

I first `SELECT` the whole data and put each row in an `Object[]`. It needs to be `Object`, since I have to store every value in that array, regardless the type.

later I will cast and convert the `Object` to a String so I can insert it into the database

**the problem**

as I said I want to get rid of the `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` Timestamps, so I need to check whether my `Timestamp` equals `'000...'`.
But in order to see what value is stored inside my `Object` I need to cast it to a `Timestamp` and that's where the `java.sql.SQLException` gets thrown to warn me that `0000....` can't be casted to a Timestamp.

**code** (this method returns a String that gets concatenated with the rest of the INSERT-Query)

```
Object column = row[columnIndex];   // column contains the value I want to check

if (column == null) {               // when its a NULL I insert my dummy value
     return "'0000-01-01 00:00:00'";
}
// here is the problem: to check if the value is 0000... I need to cast the object
// to a Timestamp.. but that's not allowed
if (((Timestamp) column).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("0000-00-00 00:00:00")) {
     return "'0000-01-01 00:00:00'";
}    

// when its neither null nor '0000... ' return the value as it is
String timestampString = ((Timestamp) column).toString();
return "'" + timestampString + "'";
```

Sorry for the long explanation.

**short question**

How do I check if a Timestamp equals `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` without casting my `Object` to a `Timestamp` ?

Comment: What about simply change your SQL statement to fit your conditions? So that you could return everytime a valid timestamp? I'm not sure about your SQL dialect, but perhaps you can solve it with a `NVL`?

Comment: You can tell the MySQL driver to return NULL for such a timestamp

Comment: You mean check for 0000 inside the SELECT-statement? Like SELECT IF(column='0000-00-00','0000-01-01',column)... ?

Comment: Yes, something like that. Sorry, I just read the mysql tag... But **a_horse_with_no_name** has probably given a good solution!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: that sounds interesting, I didn't know I could tell my driver anything.. can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: It's a connection property named `zeroDateTimeBehavior` for details see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Comment: wow, I feel so stupid now for not seeing this! Thanks, I think I'll try `zeroDateTimeBehavior=round`. It seems to do what I intended. Thank you guys for your help! BTW: @GordonLinoff: I tried casting it directly to `String` as you said but then I end up with a `ClassCastException` :/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I successfully tested your solution with `zeroDateTimeBehavior=round`, so thanks again! Why don't you write that as a short 'Answer' so I can 'accept' it for others to see? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply a connection property to the JDBC driver that will return invalid dates as `NULL`. The property is named `zeroDateTimeBehavior`

For details see the manual:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Answer (score 2):

You get the exception because the column is no Java Timestamp, but a non-Java string containing YEAR-MONTH-DAY HOURS:MINUTES:SECONDS.

Therefore you need to serialize the data into a Java String. Casting won't work in this case.

Comment: I tried your serialization suggestion, but unfortunately the two `byte[]` do not look alike. While the `byte[]` of the String actually contains `'0000-00-00...'` the serialized Object gives me always something like: `��srjava.sql.Timestamp&▒��S�eInanosxrjava.util.Datehj�KYtxpCX��x` . So even when comparing them byte by byte they never match :/ Still, nice approach! Thanks for your idea!

Comment: Right, the example didn't work, because it serializes the hole column object. I'll have a deeper look into this...those darn cross-plattform serialisations... ;)

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL Connector/J JDBC driver has a [connection property](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) that allows you to handle this:

```
zeroDateTimeBehavior
```

> What should happen when the driver encounters DATETIME values that are composed entirely of zeros (used by MySQL to represent invalid dates)? Valid values are "exception", "round" and "convertToNull".

The default is `exception`

You might want to try with `round` or `convertToNull`.